# How to add column sorting to Plotly go.Table in the column headers?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I have the below code that creates a Table that can be sorted using a drop down external to the table.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

v = [[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]
df = pd.DataFrame(v).T.sort_values(0).T

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=["A Scores", "B Scores"]), cells={"values": df.values})]
)
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "method": "restyle",
                    "label": b["l"],
                    "args": [{"cells": {"values": df.T.sort_values(b["c"]).T.values}},[0],],
                }
                for b in [{"l": "A Scores", "c": 0}, {"l": "B Scores", "c": 1}]
            ],
            "direction": "down",
            "y": 1,
        }
    ]
)
```

I want to know if it is possible to change the sorting to happen on clicking the header of the table. The application I need for this does not allow for the extra drop down.